# Unable to understand the use of these functions

Tags: eos

I was reading a smart contract and ran across these functions. I have not been able to get my head around it. Can someone explain what these fucntions do?

```
uECC_decompress()
rhash_keccak_256_init()
rhash_keccak_update()
rhash_keccak_final()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's impossible to explain those functions without the actual code of the functions. Can you post their bodies and/or provide a link to their implementation and/or API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you must have been reading either the `eosio.unregd` or `eosio.lost` contracts.

- `uECC_decompress`: Decompress a compressed public key
- `rhash_keccak_256_init(), rhash_keccak_update(), rhash_keccak_final()`: initialize, add data to, and compute a Keccak256 hash.

EDIT: Neither of these are a part of CDT. They are external libraries pulled into the project. Check the `ecc` folder in both to see the implementations.